# Error :org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am using jetpack with navigation and I implemented dependency which was in google dev's website
and I am getting error when I lunch the app please have a look and tell me what is wrong.

my Gradle:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
```

}

android {
compileSdk 32

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.g10"
    minSdk 23
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary true
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
buildFeatures {
    compose true
}
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
}
packagingOptions {
    resources {
        excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
```

//    navigation

```
def nav_version = "2.5.0"

// Java language implementation
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version")
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version")

// Kotlin
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version")
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version")

// Feature module Support
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version")

// Testing Navigation
androidTestImplementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version")

// Jetpack Compose Integration
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version")
```

}

Error:
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details

Comment: "See log for more details", Including the mentioned log would be really helpful

Comment: Please show complete stacktrace

Comment: @JunaidKhalid I just solved the problem and I post it please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just changed my kotlin version 1.7.0 to 1.5.31 and it worked very fine.

here is the my
`build.Gradle`
project file (not module file/app file)

```
plugins {

   id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.31' apply false

}
```